# How to see returned data from @wire ApexWireMethodToProperty

Tags: lightning-web-components

So, My question is how do I console the returned data from ApexWireMethodToProperty, So I used ApexWireMethodToFunction to see the data but for that, I need to create another parameter to set the data into `html.markup`

**ApexWireMethodToFunction**

```
// This component Added in Account Record Detail Page
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccountRelatedContact from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getAccountRelatedContact';

export default class ApexWireMethodToProperty extends LightningElement {
    @track conData;
    @wire(getAccountRelatedContact) accounts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
        else if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**ApexWireMethodToProperty**

The actual problem, As you see in code console is getting fail, So How do I see this data without funtion.

```
// Added in Account Record Detail Page
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccountRelatedContact from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getAccountRelatedContact';

export default class ApexWireMethodToProperty extends LightningElement {
    @track conData;
    @wire(getAccountRelatedContact) accounts;
    //console.log(accounts) - getting error because without function scope.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a getter. It will be invoked everytime the reactive property changes:

```
export default class ApexWireMethodToProperty extends LightningElement {
    @track conData;
    @wire(getAccountRelatedContact) accs;

    get accounts(){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.accs));
        return this.accs;
    }
}
```

No need to change UI since you can continue using `accounts` - as it is now getting assigned from getter

Comment: thanks for the suggestion that's what I thinking to use getter